# Combine two multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two multidimensional arrays like:

```
[a]
  [b]
    [c]
```

and

```
[a]
  [b]
    [c]
    [d]
```

and want to turn it into a single array

```
[a]
  [b]
    [c]
    [d]
```

I tried the `array_merge_recursive()` function, but it creates new elements on the last level instead of overwriting them.

For example, if `[c]` is `"X"` in the first array, and `"Y"` in the second array, I get `array("X", "Y")` instead of the last value (`"Y"`).

Comment: This appears to be the default behavior. You may need to write your own using `array_walk_recursive()` or some other UDF to perform the logic you describe.

Comment: I have a doubt, what about if 2nd array holds **[p] [q] [c][d]** this type of data? What is the expected output?

Comment: Please show us your code and the actual input and output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this what you're after, using `array_replace_recursive`?

```
<?php

$arr1 = array ('a' => array ('b' => array ('c' => 'X'), 'd' => 'array_1_d'));
$arr2 = array ('a' => array ('b' => array ('c' => 'Y', 'd' => 'Z')), 'e' => 'array_2_e');

$arr3 = array_replace_recursive ($arr1, $arr2);

var_dump($arr3);
```

Outputs:

```
array(2) {
  ["a"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["b"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["c"]=>
      string(1) "Y"
      ["d"]=>
      string(1) "Z"
    }
    ["d"]=>
    string(9) "array_1_d"
  }
  ["e"]=>
  string(9) "array_2_e"
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php

Comment: I think this is a newish function introduced about the same time as the Iterator objects... I'd overlooked it as well :)

Comment: @CD001; It's in since PHP 5.3, iterators existed long time before that.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** [Just seeing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731340/combine-two-multidimensional-arrays/7731512#7731512), a function exists for that :) : [`array_replace_recursive`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php). In case below PHP 5.3, this might still be useful:

[Union of two arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) (with string keys), recursive:

```
function array_union_recursive(Array $a, Array $b)
{
    foreach($a as $k => &$v)
    {
        if (is_array($v) && isset($b[$k]) && is_array($b[$k]))
        {
            $v = array_union_recursive($a[$k], $b[$k]);
        }
    }

    $a += $b;
    return $a;
}
```

If you want to get the last value instead of the first, you need to swap `$a` and `$b` when invoking the function but in any case you need to specify the rules somehow. That's why `array_merge_recursive` saves each value.

[Demo](http://codepad.org/kCMF6XOY)

Comment: thanks this works! but I'll go with Daren's array_replace_recursive because it's built in :D

Comment: @Alex, sure, I didn't knew it otherwise I would have suggested it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Considering two arrays:

```
<?php 
$test1 = array(array('a','b','c'), 'a', 'b'); 
$test2 = array(array('d','e'), 'c'); 
?>
```

while using overwrite merge you would expect the result to be an array:

```
<?php $test3 = array(array('d','e'), 'c', 'b'); ?>
```

However most of the functions will result with this array:

So, here's a function to do that:

```
<?php 
function array_merge_overwrite(array &$array1, array $array2 = NULL) 
{ 
    $flag = true; 
    foreach (array_keys($array2) as $key) 
    { 
        if (isset($array2[$key]) && is_array($array2[$key])) 
        { 
            if (isset($array1[$key]) && is_array($array1[$key])) 
                array_merge_overwrite($array1[$key], $array2[$key]); 
            else 
                $array1[$key] = $array2[$key]; 

            $flag = false; 
        } 
    } 

    if ($flag == true) 
        $array1 = $array2; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: If you pass an empty array as `$array2` the function will return an empty array?